# convert hourly rainfall data into daily in specific time interval

Tags: r, time-series

I have hourly rainfall and temperature data for long period. I would like to get daily values from hourly data. I am considering day means from 07:00:00 to next day 07:00:00.

Could you tell me how to convert hourly data to daily between specific time interval?

example : `07:00:00 to 07:00:00` or `12:00:00 to 12:00:00`)

Rainfall data looks like:

```
1970-01-05 00:00:00      1.0 
1970-01-05 01:00:00      1.0
1970-01-05 02:00:00      1.0
1970-01-05 03:00:00      1.0
1970-01-05 04:00:00      1.0
1970-01-05 05:00:00      3.6
1970-01-05 06:00:00      3.6
1970-01-05 07:00:00      2.2
1970-01-05 08:00:00      2.2
1970-01-05 09:00:00      2.2
1970-01-05 10:00:00      2.2
1970-01-05 11:00:00      2.2
1970-01-05 12:00:00      2.2
1970-01-05 13:00:00      2.2
1970-01-05 14:00:00      2.2
1970-01-05 15:00:00      2.2
1970-01-05 16:00:00      0.0
1970-01-05 17:00:00      0.0
1970-01-05 18:00:00      0.0
1970-01-05 19:00:00      0.0
1970-01-05 20:00:00      0.0
1970-01-05 21:00:00      0.0
1970-01-05 22:00:00      0.0
1970-01-05 23:00:00      0.0
1970-01-06 00:00:00      0.0
```

Comment: Please explain what does this line means 1970-01-05 05:00:00      3.6

Comment: It represents date and time 1970-01-05 05:00:00("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") and 3.6 rainfall(mm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can you this code :

```
fun <- function(s,i,j) { sum(s[i:(i+j-1)]) }
sapply(X=seq(1,24*nb_of_days,24),FUN=fun,s=your_time_serie,j=24)
```

You just have to change 1 to another value to have different interval of time : 8 of `07:00:00 to 07:00:00` or 13 for `12:00:00 to 12:00:00`

Answer (score 5):

First, create some reproducible data so we can help you better:

```
require(xts)
set.seed(1)
X = data.frame(When = as.Date(seq(from = ISOdatetime(2012, 01, 01, 00, 00, 00),
                                  length.out = 100, by="1 hour")),
               Measurements = sample(1:20, 100, replace=TRUE))
```

We now have a data frame with 100 hourly observations where the dates start at `2012-01-01 00:00:00` and end at `2012-01-05 03:00:00` (time is in 24-hour format).

Second, convert it to an XTS object.

```
X2 = xts(X$Measurements, order.by=X$When)
```

Third, learn how to subset a specific time window.

```
X2['T04:00/T08:00']
#                     [,1]
# 2012-01-01 04:00:00    5
# 2012-01-01 05:00:00   18
# 2012-01-01 06:00:00   19
# 2012-01-01 07:00:00   14
# 2012-01-01 08:00:00   13
# 2012-01-02 04:00:00   18
# 2012-01-02 05:00:00    7
# 2012-01-02 06:00:00   10
# 2012-01-02 07:00:00   12
# 2012-01-02 08:00:00   10
# 2012-01-03 04:00:00    9
# 2012-01-03 05:00:00    5
# 2012-01-03 06:00:00    2
# 2012-01-03 07:00:00    2
# 2012-01-03 08:00:00    7
# 2012-01-04 04:00:00   18
# 2012-01-04 05:00:00    8
# 2012-01-04 06:00:00   16
# 2012-01-04 07:00:00   20
# 2012-01-04 08:00:00    9
```

Fourth, use that information with `apply.daily` and whatever function you want, as follows:

```
apply.daily(X2['T04:00/T08:00'], mean)
#                     [,1]
# 2012-01-01 08:00:00 13.8
# 2012-01-02 08:00:00 11.4
# 2012-01-03 08:00:00  5.0
# 2012-01-04 08:00:00 14.2
```

## Update: Custom endpoints

After re-reading your question, I see that I misinterpreted what you wanted.

It seems that you want to take the mean of a 24 hour period, not necessarily from midnight to midnight.

For this, you should ditch `apply.daily` and instead, use `period.apply` with custom `endpoint`s, like this:

```
# You want to start at 7AM. Find out which record is the first one at 7AM.
A = which(as.character(index(X2)) == "2012-01-01 07:00:00")

# Use that to create your endpoints. 
# The ends of the endpoints should start at 0 
# and end at the max number of records.
ep = c(0, seq(A, 100, by=24), 100)
period.apply(X2, INDEX=ep, FUN=function(x) mean(x))
#                         [,1]
# 2012-01-01 07:00:00 12.62500
# 2012-01-02 07:00:00 10.08333
# 2012-01-03 07:00:00 10.79167
# 2012-01-04 07:00:00 11.54167
# 2012-01-05 03:00:00 10.25000
```

Comment: @Andrie, thanks, but it seems I had misread the OPs question. They want to aggregate starting from a time on day one and ending on the subsequent day--so basically shifting the start and end of `apply.daily`. Post now updated.

Answer (score 2):

Step 1: transform date to POSIXct

```
ttt <- as.POSIXct("1970-01-05 08:00:00",tz="GMT")
ttt
#"1970-01-05 08:00:00 GMT"
```

Step 2: substract difftime of 7 hours

```
ttt <- ttt-as.difftime(7,units="hours")
ttt
#"1970-01-05 01:00:00 GMT"
```

Step 3: trunc to days

```
ttt<-trunc(ttt,"days")
ttt
#"1970-01-05 GMT"
```

Step 4: use plyr, data.table or whatever method you prefer, to calculate daily means

Answer (score 0):

Using [regular expressions](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/R_Programming/Text_Processing#Regular_Expressions) should get you what you need. Select lines that match your needs and sum the values. Do this for each day within your hour range and you're set.